# MVC Web API Report

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, reporting-services, rdlc

Im trying to solve an issue in MVC4. 
**Background:**
We have an existing asp.net web application where we have reports section. These are rdlc files with datasource and dataset configured to use an SP to populate the rows which is tied to an aspx view. All these are regular stuff. We have migrated the existing application to MVC rest based web app and apis. Here, the web app send/receive data in json format and used in view accordingly. 
**Problem to solve:**
the data required for the report to show is coming from one of the rest apis which returns json object. The report (.rdlc) traditionally connects to a DB, but in my case, the data is in json. How will I go about mapping the json data to the report view?
Searched lot of forums for couple of days, no real success. Inputs greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a local report? In server reports the data is not usually returned as json.

Comment: right. This report does not connect to the server to fetch data. The data is available as api response in json format. this needs to be tied to the report view.

Comment: This seems relevant --> http://spacefold.com/lisa/post/2011/10/14/Actual-Factual-JSON-data-in-SSRS.aspx

Comment: thanks for proving the link. Will check if their solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same situation for our ASP.Net MVC application where the RESTful web services pass back JSON data to the front end applications. The MVC application doesn't just provide data, it applies business rules to the data before passing it back and these business rules can't be applied at the database level. So reporting is not straightforward.

We wanted to call these same web services to get the same data as the front end applications get. Fortunately SSRS is amazingly extensible. I created a [custom data processing extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that calls our ASP.Net MVC controllers and returns the data, which is deserialised into datasets for use in the reports.

While not trivial, it isn't as hard as you might think and implementing a custom data processing extension is a good way to solve your problem. There are plenty of examples online to get you started. I based mine on the [file share example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160918(v=sql.90).aspx) provided with SSRS that queries a network folder and returns the file information as a dataset.

Comment: Decided to move from using rdlc to use Jquery Datable to display the records. Thanks for the inputs .